# Call a fragmentMethod from another fragment, but can't refer to them in parentFragmentActivity's View pager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I m new to android and i m having trouble with fragment communication, reading about it discovered the standard method of creating an interface and implementing it from the parentActivity which doesn't work in my case which is as follows.

*I have an Activity named as ActivityA which extends fragment activity,in which i have a view pager for i want to keep two fragments namely fragmentA and fragmentB which should be swipable fragments.*

*fragmentA has a button which onClicked should make a change in fragmentB, to be precise on click it should add a string in the listView in fragmentA.
Now i have created the both the fragments's layouts as well as added the viewPAger to my FragmentActivity, they work great on swiping, the function is executed onButtonClick of fragmentA and logic works perfectly, after this is i want the changes to be reflected in fragmentB.
Using the interface method i can't find the reference to my fragment by id as it is added by viewPager to ActivityA*

How do i do this??
help me out.

Stackoverflow says don't ask questions with out code so
**Here is the Sample code**

Activity A which has a virewPAger, need help how to get my fragment's Reference from the viewPager

```
public class ActivityA extends FragmentActivity  implements FragmentA.Communicator
    {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_A);
            viewPager= (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
            viewPager.setAdapter(new myAdapter(fragmentManager));
        }

    class myAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

        public myAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
            super(fragmentManager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            switch (i){
                case 0: fragment = new listOfIDsScanned();
                    break;
                case 1: fragment = new displayCounter();
                    break;

                default: //something witch won't crush the app
                    break;
            }
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }
    }
```

This is fragmentA , actual fragment name is something else just for simple representation calling it fragmentA, which has an interface Communicator to communicate between fragments

```
public class fragmentA extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements View.OnClickListener
{

    TextView counter;
    Button scanStudentID;
    int count=0;
    String name=null,rollNo=null;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.display_counter,container,false);
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        scanStudentID= (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.startScanning);
        scanStudentID.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.startScanning:
                startScanning();
                break;
        }
    }

    public void startScanning()
    {
        startActivityForResult(new Intent(getActivity(),Barcode.class),1);
    }

public interface Communicator
{
     // necessary methods
}
}
```

now finally fragmentB, in which methodToBeCalled(parameters) has to be invoked on the button click in fragementA

```
public class fragementB extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
{
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<String> rollNo= new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> studentName= new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_of_ids_scanned,container,false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        listView= (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView);
    }

    public void  methodToBeCalled(String rollNo,String studentName)
    {
        if(!alreadyScanned(rollNo))
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

    boolean alreadyScanned(String rollNo)
    {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you read the official Documentation ? http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: @ShifarShifz, i did & that is what it's all about, using the viewPager i can't find the fragment by id. Did You read my entire question?